# Why is syntax highlighting different when added via tag or via <!-- language: lang-XXX -->

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Take [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/683234/get-value-between-two-commas-using-vba/684204#684204) where the tag `VBA` is used. The system recognizes the tag and automatically turns on syntax highlighting. So far so good.

Today I answered [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/813428/microsoft-word-convert-tracked-changes-to-highlighted/813440#813440) where no syntax highlighting was enabled. I tried to enable it myself with `<!-- language: lang-VBA -->`. It worked.

But they seem to be different. Here's a direct comparison:

[image]
<sup>via `<!-- language: lang-VBA -->`</sup>

[image]
<sup>via tag `VBA`</sup>

My question is: What's the reason behind this? Is it intentional?

---

#### Edit as reply @Sathya

Either I'm too dumb or we have a misunderstanding here. Let's make an experiment and play around with [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/813428/convert-tracked-changes-to-highlighted/813440#813440)

**VBA comment:** First, we insert `<!-- language: lang-VBA -->` and have a look at the preview after some seconds.

[image]

**VB comment:** Next we change `<!-- language: lang-VBA -->` to `<!-- language: lang-VB -->`. Wait some seconds between your actions.

[image]

**VBA tag:** In the last step, we remove the comment completely. Again, wait some seconds and click somewhere else

[image]

As I see it, there is no difference between applying `<!-- language: lang-VBA -->` or `<!-- language: lang-VB -->`. Both methods result in the same highlighting. Or am I blind?

In comparison the last try where nothing is inserted has a completely different result. That's where the tag `VBA` from the question itself takes effect

Comment: Sometimes cat-like smiley faces find really neat things.

Comment: Post the link to both your answers?

Comment: [tag:vba] applies `lang-vb` not `lang-VB`. Case matters,

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't mentioned the other question, the only answer you'd posted to day was [this](https://superuser.com/a/813440/4377).

On [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/683234/get-value-between-two-commas-using-vba/684204#684204), the question is tagged with [vba](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vba). Looking at the tag definition, the syntax highlighting language is set as vb, so the prettifier `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` why is why you see the highlighting as in the second image.

On your today's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/813440/4377), the question originally didn't have [vba](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vba), so no syntax highlighting was applied.

Then, you forced `<!-- language: lang-VBA -->` which has different colour syntax highlighting than `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` which is applied to the first question.

hence, the difference. See the [revisions here](https://superuser.com/posts/813440/revisions) to see how the highlighting changes

Comment: Erm, I cannot reproduce nor understand this answer. You say a question tagged with `VBA` should give the same syntax highlightning as when inserted `<!-- language: lang-VB -->`? That's simply not the case

Comment: @nixda see my edit